# Regex for matching 1 character a uppercase letter, 2nd could be letter / number, rest numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a regular expression test a certain type of string It works well but some part of me says I am not sure if there are exception that invalidates it.

type of string I need to validate are these.

'GX2480', 'H03667', 'HQ2999'

regular expression I wrote is `"^[A-Z]{0,1}[A-Z0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}$"`

Here is the JSBin in case anyone wants to experiment.

https://jsbin.com/yikuqonepu/edit?html,js,console

EDIT: To further help others I was primarily looking to identify 6 char string with first letter being an alphabet and second could be either number/alphabet and last 4 as numbers thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"^[A-Z]{0,1}[A-Z0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}$"` would also match an input of only numbers or an empty input since everything is optional.

If you want to force your input to start with a letter, don't make it optional:
`"^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]?[0-9]{0,4}$"`

Valid inputs:

- "A"
- "AB"
- "A1"
- "AB1"
- "AB1234"
- "A12345"

Invalid inputs:

- ""
- "ABC"
- "AB12345"
- "AB12C"
- "1"
- "123"

---

If the real question is how to match input strings of *exactly* length 6, the first character always being a letter, the last 4 characters always digits and the second character lettor or digit, then the regex would be:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]{4}$
```

Valid inputs:

- "AB1234"
- "A12345"

Invalid inputs:

- "A"
- "AB"
- "A1"
- "AB1"
- ""
- "ABC"
- "AB12345"
- "AB12C"
- "AB123C"
- "ABC123"
- "1"
- "123"

Alternatively, it could be formulated as follows, perhaps this is more explicit of the two different forms of inputs you allow:

```
^([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z][0-9]{5})$
```

Comment: Hi @knittl thanks for answering I didn’t understood the part of making them optional? What I want to achieve here is that length of each string is 6 characters and the curly braces I placed my understanding says first character will be an alphabet second could be a number / alphabet and the last 4 should be numbers. Please correct me thanks!

Comment: And most importantly thanks I don’t want A, AB to be part of it so a character of fixed length 6 I must say is there any way to enforce that using regex I suppose not?

Comment: @DivyanshuRawat so you only want to match inputs of length 6? The regex from your question has all parts optional (`{0,1}` means 0 to 1 repetitions, `{0,4}` means 0 to 4 repetitions)

Comment: Thanks a lot @knittl for taking time to answer the question! I really appreciate it. :) I didn’t knew that {} here means repetitions, once again to clarify it a bit if I write [0-9]{0,4} it means I am expecting any number 0 to 9 getting repeated 4 times? like 2222, 4444?

Comment: another question @knittl in the new expression ^[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]{4}$ here ^[A-Z] represents first char and [A-Z0-9] represent second and [0-9]{4}$ represent last 4 right?

Comment: @DivyanshuRawat no, `[0-9]{0,4}` means any number repeated 0 to 4 times. So "" (empty input), "7", "42", "420", "1337" are all matched by this regex.

Comment: @DivyanshuRawat "^[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]{4}$ here ^[A-Z] represents first char and [A-Z0-9] represent second and [0-9]{4}$ represent last 4 right?" – yes, correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can test your regular expression online. The following link is one of the examples.

- https://www.regextester.com

And your regex accepts string like '', '0', 'H0' because you accept the {0} number of characters and numbers. I would change the regex into this:

```
"^[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]{4}$"
```

Comment: `[A-Z]{1}` is just `[A-Z]`

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong my understanding of curly braces are that when I wrote { 0, 1 } then I meant the first character in my string is a Upper case alphabet and the second could be number / alphabet and last 4 will be numbers.

Comment: @DivyanshuRawat For example [`^[A-Z]{0,1}[0-9]$` matches e.g. `1`, `A1`,...](https://regex101.com/r/R0RIZ9/1) where `{0,1}` is the same like `?` and means [*optional*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). Further using `{1}` is afaik always redundant as the preceding token requires to be matched *once* by default.

Comment: thanks @bobble for taking time to answer the question! I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are straight forward. Here is an educational one, where you can use a positive lookahead for required number of chars, and a pattern of expected cars. This approach is useful when the pattern of expected chars is complex (more complex than your example).

```js
[
  'GX2480', 'H03667', 'HQ2999', // ok
  'HQ2', 'HQ299999', '123456', '123', 'AAA123' // not ok
].forEach(str => {
  let ok = /^(?=.{6}$)[A-Z][A-Z]?[0-9]*$/.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' => ' + ok);
});
```

Output:

```
GX2480 => true
H03667 => true
HQ2999 => true
HQ2 => false
HQ299999 => false
123456 => false
123 => false
AAA123 => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?=.{6}$)` -- positive lookahead for 6 chars
- `[A-Z][A-Z]?` -- expect 1 or two uppercase cars, same as `[A-Z]{1,2}`
- `[0-9]*` -- optional digits
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

Comment: Thanks a lot @peter for taking time to answer the question! I really appreciate it. :)